# How to change the opacity of a form that the child of "Progman" in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, opacity, desktop

hello I'm trying to make a gadget for my app, and I found a way to make UnMinimizeable which to make the Desktop "Progman" the parent of the gadget form. but there is one problem: I can change the opacity of the form. Here is the code:

Make Progman the parent of the form

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindow(lpClassName As String, lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SetParent(hWndChild As IntPtr, hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Private desktopHandle As IntPtr = FindWindow("Progman", Nothing) 'Progman is the real name of Desktop
'WinForms Form

Private Sub SwitchParent()
    Me.Show()
    SetParent(Me.Handle, desktopHandle)
    Me.SendToBack()
End Sub
```

Change Opacity of the form

```
Me.Opacity = 0.5
```

it returns this exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
   ErrorCode=-2147467259
   Message=The parameter is incorrect
   NativeErrorCode=87
   Source=System.Windows.Forms
```

Comment: Setting layered window attributes, like Opacity, is only supported on Windows versions < 8 on top-level windows.  A top-level window is distinct by it not having a parent.  Maybe you can get it going by setting the Opacity *before* setting the parent.  But do keep in mind that SetParent() using a window of another process is an appcompat hack for Windows 3.x programs.  It is not 1992 anymore, YMMV.

Comment: I'd be very grateful If you explain this more to me, "But do keep in mind that SetParent() using a window of another process is an appcompat hack for Windows 3.x programs". Is there a better way to do so??
I set my form parent to Progman so that it won't minimize when the user presses Win+D.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/17/10175502.aspx

Comment: THank you very much, btw changing the opacity before setting the parent DID work!. Thank you again :) . I don't think it's illegal to set desktop to my form's parent as there are other examples that have already done it, like: Stardocks.